# Should Politics.SE have custom badge images?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, design

Many sites in the Stack Exchange network have custom badge images, for example [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/badges), [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges), & [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Should Politics.SE also implement this feature when we get a design? If so, please suggest which icon(s) we could use for this purpose.

Comment: A custom site design is one of the perks of graduation. I don't expect any changes to the theme while in beta.

Comment: @yannis Thanks, edited. I believe I'm correct in saying that not all graduated sites have custom badges though?

Comment: Yes. There's a large backlog of graduated sites waiting for their designs. Some have been waiting for years. For more details: [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/162704)

Comment: @yannis iirc 2 beta sites got designs (those were special cases though)

Answer (score 12):

If we're going to go this route, I would suggest a check inside the box. Something similar to [this Font Awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/check-square)

[image]

1. It's a neutral symbol
2. It reminds us of voting (inherently political)
3. It's easy to do

Comment: IMHO, the rosettes look a lot more spiffy tho.

Comment: A politically correct answer...

Comment: Don't most elections run with an X rather than a tick?

Answer (score 3):

I think custom badges could be a way to further distinguish the site from others in the network, as well as another step down the pathway to moving out of Beta. I suggest that the icon used could be a rosette similar to campaign rosettes worn in some countries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's nothing about that that specifically says "campaign" or "politics" to me.  The first thing that comes to mind is prize ribbons from various competitions / state fairs / races, etc. My suggestion would be an outline (or silhouette) of a waving flag, but I don't know if I can put an example together.

Comment: I haven't seen those rosettes being used in a politician context outside the UK.

Comment: @Sjoerd I did wonder, but a cursory check showed results for their use in other countries; possibly "many" is an exaggeration though

Answer (score -3):

I finally got a chance to make the flag icons I mentioned in my comment on CDJB's answer.  I used [this free icon](http://simpleicon.com/flag.html) as the template.

[image: bronze flag] [image: silver flag] [image: gold flag]

Flags are one of (if not *the*) primary symbols for a country, so they're inherently political.

---

I'm not sure this is any better or worse than the checkmark, it just has a different slant.  Flags lean more towards external politics, of and between nations, while checkmarks would be more suggestive of internal politics, between a government and its citizens.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess some[one] was not into flag waving...

Comment: @Fizz - Apparently not.  Hopefully someone who dislikes the idea will explain why they do.  It could just be the same 1-2 people who downvoted on the other answers, though.

Comment: I guess my largest objection here would be that these look like the comment flag icon

Comment: I didn't downvote this either, so their reasoning is anyone's guess. But no answer has escaped downvoters